# jpql variable that can be null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an jpql query inside a JpaRepository like this:

```
@Query("select l from LogEntity l where l.codePackage = :codePackage and l.codeFile = :codeFile order by l.id desc")
public Page<LogEntity> findSimilarAngularLog (@Param("codePackage") String codePackage, @Param("codeFile") String codeFile, Pageable pageRequest);
```

The variable `codePackage` and `codeFile` can be NULL. But hibernate is always making something like

```
... where l.codePackage=? and l.codeFile=? ...
```

out of it. So if one or both of them are NULL, then there is `l.codeFile=NULL` and not `l.codeFile IS NULL`. And then he does not find anything at all.
If I copy the hibernate generated sql string to my MySQL console and change the `=NULL` to `IS NULL`, he will find everything.

So how do I change the behavior of hibernate jpa, so that in my `@Query` String the NULL will be treated correctly.

thanks a lot and greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query for that:

```
@Query("select l from LogEntity l where ((:codePackage is null and l.codePackage is null) or l.codePackage = :codePackage) and ((:codeFile is null and l.codeFile is null) or l.codeFile = :codeFile) order by l.id desc")
```

But wouldn't that be a good idea to make hql through the logic rather than using it like the named queries?

A better logic would be to use an if condition, like,

```
if(codePackage == null) {
    query += " l.codePackage is null ";
}
else {
    query += " l.codePackage = :codePackage ";
}
***code***
//query execution code
```

Comment: I am using a JpaRepository interface, so it is not possible to use program logic, because the function really only is the `@Query(...) public something(...parameter...)`. Or am I overseeng something?

Comment: You must be having the object of entity manager. You can use entity manager to fire your queries. Otherwise the first solution can be implemented anytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ((:param is null and t.field is null) or t.field = :param)
@Query("select l from LogEntity l where ((:codePackage is null and l.codePackage is null) or l.codePackage = :codePackage ) and ((:codeFile is null and l.codeFile is null) or l.codeFile = :codeFile ) order by l.id desc")
```